# Android Custom ListView Adapter Not Working: Crashes with no error message

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android and followed slidenerd's tutorial on youtube. Here is my code. For some reason, it crashes without giving an error. It works with the regular adapter from android but the custom one doesnt work. Please help. Thanks.

```
public List<String> teamsList = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> teamCities = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> teamDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.teamsList);
    mListView.setAdapter(new TeamsAdapter(this, teamsList, teamCities, teamDates));

class SingleRow {

    String team;
    String city;
    String date;

    public SingleRow(String team, String city, String date) {

        this.team = team;
        this.city = city;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

class TeamsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<SingleRow> list;

    Context c;

    public TeamsAdapter(Context c, List<String> teamsList, List<String> teamCities, List<String> teamDates) {

        this.c = c;

        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

        String[] teams = teamsList.toArray(new String[teamsList.size()]);
        String[] cities = teamCities.toArray(new String[teamCities.size()]);
        String[] dates = teamDates.toArray(new String[teamDates.size()]);

        for (int i=0;i<teams.length;i++) {
            list.add(new SingleRow(teams[i], cities[i], dates[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_row, parent, false);
        TextView team = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.team);
        TextView city = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.city);
        TextView date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date);
        SingleRow temp = list.get(position);
        team.setText(temp.team);
        city.setText(temp.city);
        date.setText(temp.date);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean there's no error message? If your app crashes, there's always something in logcat. Is there really nothing there?

Comment: there actually is nothing there. usually i get a fatal error but this time its absolutely nothing.

Comment: I find that really, really odd. Try putting custom log calls in above code of yours to see how far it gets so you can track down the line where it fails.

Comment: I put a try catch and it didn't go into the catch. But I built the app multiple times and it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the inflater. If you are using an Activity, try passing the LayoutInflater in your TeamsAdapter's contructor instead of the Context.

```
 public TeamsAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<String> teamsList, List<String> teamCities, List<String> teamDates)
{
  this.mInflater = inflater;
...
}
```

In your getView function:

```
View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.team_row, parent, false);
```

In your code where you instantiate the TeamsAdapter and I am assuming it is an Activity derived class, do the following:

```
teamsAdapter =  new TeamsAdapter(this.getLayoutInflater(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are inflating cell view to parent viewgroup?

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_row, null, false);
```

Try to use null instead, I'm not sure that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current contents of your question, heres my guess:

The first time an adapter view calls getView (when setAdapter is called), the convertview argument is always null.  So, you wont be able to get a layout inflater from that arg. Change it to use the `LayoutInflater.from(Context context)` method instead using the parent.getContext() as the context.   Something like,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext)
    ...
```

Moving forward, here is a kick ass article on how to do adapters really well.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

HTHs